# Error:(14, 26) error: package com.android.molley does not exist

Tags: java, android, import, setcontentview

I'm new in an android studio, and when I import this code, and I rebuild the project I've this error message, my question's how I can resolve this problem:
Error:(14, 26) error: package com.android.molley does not exist
Error:(30, 16) error: cannot find symbol class SetContentView

And this is my code:

```
import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity;
import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.molley.SetContentView;
import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesActivityResultCodes;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdAdMobBridge;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdAppLovinBridge;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdChartboostBridge;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdFacebookBridge;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdHeyzapBridge;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdLeadBoltBridge;
import com.secrethq.ads.PTAdRevMobBridge;
import com.secrethq.store.PTStoreBridge;
import com.secrethq.utils.PTJniHelper;
import com.secrethq.utils.PTServicesBridge;

public class PTPlayer extends Cocos2dxActivity {

private static native void loadModelController();
public static SetContentView setContentView;
public static Activity activity;
public static Context context;
public static boolean wait = true;
```

Comment: Seems like a duplicate for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034984/cannot-find-symbol-class-setcontentview

Comment: Yes, but the problem had not been solved, that's why I post my case.

Comment: Where did you get / copy the line `import com.android.molley.SetContentView;` from?   If you tell us, perhaps someone can track down the source of this nonsense ... and provide a definitive answer.

Comment: Try this way that will definitely work https://stackoverflow.com/a/50073558/3514144